# How to limit motor stall current?

Tags: current, motor

I've run into a dilemma. I have two motors, both with a 2.2A stall current. I know that at start up, motors will draw their stall current because they are essentially stalled. However, my motor driver is rated at 2A max per bridge (there are two), and my battery is rated at a max discharge rate of 3.5A.

Is there any way I can limit the stall current? Could I implement a sort of "soft start" using PWM to slowly turn the motor?

Comment: Not an answer, because wild speculation: the motor's inductance gives you a slow start if the motor isn't stuck.

Comment: Here's a very radical idea that I think is worth considering:  *Use drivers that are rated for the motors you are using instead of under-rated ones.* You'll only end up blowing them up otherwise.

Comment: Soft start using PWM is an accepted technique.

Comment: What drivers are you using for the motors?

Comment: What happens if you try and draw to much current from the driver?  Maybe it will self limit? (or maybe it can do 2.2A for a short time.)

Comment: @Majenko The idea of rating the drivers for continuously delivering the stall current is a good idea indeed, and it's worth considering. Especially when we are talking only about a couple of Amperes. [continued below]

Comment: @Majenko On the other hand, I was once in a situation when the motor would draw 20A when stalled and 10A when cruising. If a smaller driver can supply a larger peak/overload current, and I can match it to the peak demand, then I can use a smaller driver. Timing would be of essence, because an overload shouldn't last too long. This also depends on the usage of the motor: does it mostly cruise, or does it start and stall a lot.

Comment: How about if you charge up a big capacitor and dump it into the motor to get it started, then switch the motor over to the driver?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use PWM to reduce the average voltage to the motor, which will reduce the average stall current.

Depending on the inductance of the motor and the impedance of the supply and your PWM frequency, the peak current may still be >2A, which may or may not matter to your driver, depending one where its 2A limit comes from.

In real life you'll find that your drivers are undersized and you should do the job properly now.